# get result of query with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fetch two events using the following query provided there is an entry in events table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.* 
    FROM 
        events e
    WHERE 
        e.id= 654321
        AND e.sub_type_id = 78
        AND e.type_id = 230
        AND e.cid = 123
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        e1.* 
    FROM 
        events e1
    WHERE 
        e1.id< 654321
        AND e1.sub_type_id = 78
        AND e1.type_id = 230
        AND e1.cid = 123
) as sub
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 2;
```

This query will work fine for 2nd event entry and so on since I get two records but for the first event, I want problem_description so I modified the query as follows -

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.*,
        rd.problem_description
    FROM 
        events e
        JOIN request_details rd ON( rd.cid = e.cid AND rd.request_id = e.data_reference_id)
    WHERE 
        e.id= 654321
        AND e.sub_type_id = 78
        AND e.type_id = 230
        AND e.cid = 123
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        e1.*,
        rd1.problem_description     
    FROM 
        events e1
        JOIN request_details rd1 ON( rd1.cid = e1.cid AND rd1.request_id = e1.data_reference_id)
    WHERE 
        e1.id< 654321
        AND e1.sub_type_id = 78
        AND e1.type_id = 230
        AND e1.cid = 123
) as sub
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 2;
```

I am confused about which type of join should I use since for the first entry there will not be any record in the database for events but there is a record for problem_description.

Comment: MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: And why are you using `UNION ALL`? Couldn't you just use `e1.data_reference_id <= 654321`

Comment: @Gurwinder postgres

Comment: @Gurwinder : I am trying to get two event results and combining them hence using union all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UNION ALL` seems useless when you can use `e1.data_reference_id <= 654321` instead.

Also, I think all you need is a right join if the records always exists in the right table request_details and sometimes in the events table.

```
select e.*,
    r.problem_description
from events e
right join request_details r on e.cid = e.cid
    and r.request_id = e.data_reference_id
where e.data_reference_id <= 654321
    and e.sub_type_id = 78
    and e.type_id = 230
    and e.cid = 123
order by e.id desc limit 2;
```